# Unexpect string format behaviour

Tags: python, format, boolean, alignment

I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour with how `str.format()` handles bool types when specifying alignment.  Here's the example:

```
>>> '{}'.format(bool(1))
True

>>> '{:<}'.format(bool(1))
1
```

Notice -- when I specified alignment, `format` switched to displaying an integer instead of `True` (I wanted to display the bool, not an integer).  I can force the desired output by casting the bool to string thusly:

```
>>> '{:<}'.format(str(bool(1)))
True
```

My question is -- can anyone explain this edge case in `str.format()` ?

Comment: Note that `'{!s:<}'.format(True)` also explicitly converts to string while allowing alignment.

Comment: When format `<` is specified Python will call `__format__` on the object first: `True.__format__('<')` -> `'1'`. If `!r` or `!s` are present then it becomes: `True.__str__().__format__('<')`.